# How to create auto update?

Tags: c#

Ok i have searched for this and cannot find specifically what im looking for. Right now all i need is how to get the exe to download to the current folder its in and when it does i need it to switch out with the old update, like overwrite it or something. All together what i want is when i click the check for update button it checks to see if there is an update, if there is it says would you like to download yes or no and you click yes then it downloads it to the current folder its in and it overwrites the old update with the new update. And if there isnt an update then it says something like you have current version.
Im using an xml file that has the version and where the download is located on my website btw.

This is what i have,

```
private void checkForUpdatesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string downloadUrl = "";
    Version newVersion = null;
    string aboutUpdate = "";
    string xmlUrl = "";
    XmlTextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlUrl);
        reader.MoveToContent();
        string elementName = "";
        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "appinfo"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    elementName = reader.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) && (reader.HasValue)) 
                        switch (elementName)
                        {
                            case "version":
                                newVersion = new Version(reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case "url":
                                downloadUrl = reader.Value;
                                break;
                            case "about":
                                aboutUpdate = reader.Value;
                                break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
    Version applicationVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    if (applicationVersion.CompareTo(newVersion) < 0)
    {
        string str = String.Format("New version found!\nYour version: {0}.\nNewest version: {1}. \nAdded in this version: {2}. ", applicationVersion, newVersion, aboutUpdate);
        if (DialogResult.No != MessageBox.Show(str + "\nDo You Want To Download This ?", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
        {
            try
            {
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile("", "");
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Looks Like You Have The Most Current Update " + applicationVersion + "!", "Update", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None);
    }
}
```

If anyone can help please do, i have searched and tried everything, thank you .

Comment: Is there a reason that you're trying to reinvent ClickOnce?

Comment: Is the problem with the XML processing or the updating?

Comment: You remind me of myself when I first started...

Comment: @48klocs what do you mean?

Comment: @cahinton No i just dont know how to get the file to download to the current folder and then switch the old update with the new one

Comment: He is referring to ClickOnce, a deployment model that supports automatic updates. You can control whether updates are optional or required. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx

Comment: @Jay with click once would i be able to download to the current folder and switch the old update with the new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion: Don't reinvent the wheel. MS provides built-in functionality/project types for auto-updating applications. This is called **ClickOnce**. Here's a link to help you get started: [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx)

If you are using the latest versions of VS and .NET, you also have other choices, such as web or cloud (Azure) based deployment.

Here's a more comprehensive deployment page: [Deploying Applications, Services, and Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz.aspx)